# Replacing parts of a String using RegEx - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace the 'parameters' in my string with the actual values of the parameters using the replace() method, but for some reason I cannot get it it to work. The string I am using is:

```
var temp = "This {{application}} will be down from {{start}} to {{finish}}."
```

I want to replace {{application}} with the application name, and so on.

```
var regEx = /{{(.*?)}}/;
```

This is the regex I use to grab the values between the brackets and that part works. Here is the rest of my code:

```
if (regEx.exec(temp)[1] === "application") {
     temp.replace(regEx, params.value);
}
```

'params.value' is the name of the application. I thought this would work, but it is not.

Comment: why not just use simple plain replace? https://jsfiddle.net/th6crbbm/

Comment: I tried to. For some reason it is not working.

Comment: and the solution is to switch to regex?!?!

Comment: you know, you are missing a semicolon at the end on your `var temp =......` maybe thats why replace doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback inside a replace to evaluate the capture group contents:

```js
var name = "Google";
var temp = "This {{application}} will be down from {{start}} to {{finish}}.";
var res = temp.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (m, g) {
  return g === "application" ? name : m;
});
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

Here, `m` is the whole matched text with braces and `g` is the submatch without braces.

Answer (score 1):

**To replace only a single string(static)**

```
var appName = "application"; // String to replace
var regex = new RegExp("{{" + appName + "}}", "g"); // Use `g` flag to replace all occurrences of `{{application}}`
temp = temp.replace(regex, param.value);
```

```js
var appName = "application",
    regex = new RegExp("{{" + appName + "}}", "g"),
    temp = "This {{application}} will be down from {{start}} to {{finish}}.";

var param = {
    value: 'StackOverflow'
};
temp = temp.replace(regex, param.value);

console.log(temp);
document.body.innerHTML = temp;
```

---

**To replace all the strings inside brackets by their respective values(Dynamic)**

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with an object to replace values.

```
var regex = /{{(.*?)}}/g;
// Match all the strings in the `{{` and `}}`
// And put the value without brackets in captured group

temp = temp.replace(regex, function(m, firstGroup) {
    // m: Complete string i.e. `{{foobar}}`
    // firstGroup: The string inside the brackets

    return params[firstGroup] || 'Value not found in params';
    // If the value for the key exists in the `params` object
    //     replace the string by that value
    // else
    //     replace by some default string
});
```

```js
var params = {
    application: 'Stack Overflow',
    start: 'On Sunrise',
    finish: 'In Dreams'
};

var temp = "This {{application}} will be down from {{start}} to {{finish}}.";

var regex = /{{(.*?)}}/g;
temp = temp.replace(regex, function(m, firstGroup) {
    return params[firstGroup] || 'Value not found in params';
});

console.log(temp);
document.body.innerHTML = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an helper function to produce what you expect

```
function replace(str, dict) {
    return str.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function(match, $1) {
        return dict[$1] || match;
    });
}

replace(
    "This {{application}} will be down from {{start}} to {{finish}}.",
    {
        'application': 'pigeon',
        'start': '8am',
        'finish': '9pm'
    }
);
// "This pigeon will be down from 8am to 9pm."
```

This will accept a mapping of values to replace and the replacement. And returns the string correctly formatted.

Comment: This will only replace the first occurrence of each marker.

Comment: You are right ! So yeah ... regex are mandatory (or an ugly loop) :). I edit for a regex.